# smooth vs. analytic in the definition of almost-complex manifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds, analyticity, almost-complex

Let $A_{\infty}\hspace{-0.03 in}$ be a [maximal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Compatible_atlases) $C^{\infty}\hspace{-0.02 in}$ [atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Atlases) on $M\hspace{-0.03 in}$, and with that [smooth structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_structure) on $M$,

suppose $\: j : TM\to TM\:$ is a smooth function such that

$\;\;\;$ for all vectors $v$ in [TM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle), $\: \hspace{.03 in}j\hspace{.02 in}(\hspace{.05 in}j\hspace{.02 in}(v)) = -v \:$ and $\: \pi \hspace{.03 in}(\hspace{.05 in}j\hspace{.02 in}(v)) = \pi \hspace{.03 in}(v) \:$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ and
$\;\;\;$ for all points $p$ in $M\hspace{-0.03 in}$, the function $\: \hspace{.04 in}f : T_{\hspace{-0.03 in}p}\hspace{.03 in}M\to $ [$T_{\hspace{-0.03 in}p}\hspace{.03 in}M$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) $\:$ given by $\: \hspace{.04 in}f(v) = \hspace{.03 in}j\hspace{.02 in}(v) \:$ is a [linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map)

.
Does it follow that there is a unique subset $A_j$ of $A_{\infty}$ such that

$A_j$ is a maximal [real analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Definition) atlas on $M$ and $A_j$ makes $\hspace{.02 in}j$ real analytic?

(This question is due to [wikipedia's definition of almost-complex manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold)

only requiring smoothness, rather than real analyticity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ has (real) dimension $2$, then the answer is yes. Every $2$-dimensional almost complex structure is integrable, and the Newlander-Nirenberg theorem says that it determines a unique complex structure, i.e., a maximal atlas of holomorphically compatible charts. This atlas is, in particular, real-analytic.

But in higher dimensions, the answer is no. For example, you could start with the standard integrable almost complex structure on $\mathbb C^2$, and then use a bump function to modify it in some open set to make it non-integrable there. The result is an almost complex structure $j$ whose [Nijenhuis tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold#Integrable_almost_complex_structures) is zero on an open set but not globally zero. If $j$ were real-analytic with respect to some analytic structure, then this would be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The Morrey-Grauert theorem does say that every smooth manifold has a unique analytic structure. I don't see any reason why $j$ would automatically be analytic, but the space of almost complex structures is a fiber bundle over $M$ with fiber the symmetric space $SO(2n)/U(n)$, which is in particular a manifold, so you should be able to perturb $j$ to be analytic.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? $\:$ The places I've found it mentioned tend to disagree about what that theorem says, and some of them report the theorem as only claiming uniqueness up to smooth conjugation. $\:$ (As far as I can see, even smoothly conjugate structures could disagree about whether or not $\hspace{.03 in}j$ is analytic.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: The claim that every smooth manifold has a unique analytic structure (up to $C^\omega$ diffeomorphism) should be proved in Hirsch's differential topology book, somewhere in chapter 2, I think.

Comment: The uniqueness is subtle, to be sure. All analytic manifolds with a given underlying smooth manifold are analytically isomorphic, but that's not the same as.claiming there's a unique analytic subatlas. I don't find the latter a natural way to think,  I'm afraid.